# Using a Table of Column Definitions to Create an Insert Query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table called `raw_data` that contains a column with a large string of data fields formatted in fixed length sub-strings. I also have a table `table_1` that specifies the column name and the data range in the string for each value. I need to create a SQL `INSERT` statement to move data from `raw_data` into a table called `table_2` with all the columns.  `table_1` has about 600 rows, so I am wondering if I can loop through each record to create the SQL statement that inserts the data into `table_2`.

```
Table_1
    Name    Start    Length
    AAA       1       2
    BBB       3       3
    CCC       6       1
```

I haven't learned how to use cursors; the below query could be incorrect. There will be 3 tables involved in this task. `table_1` to look up the name, start, length values. `table_2` will be the table I need to insert the data into. The third table `raw_data` has the column with the sub-strings of each needed value.

```
 DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(200) 
    DECLARE @NAME VARCHAR(200) 
    DECLARE @START VARCHAR(200)  
    DECLARE @LENGTH VARCHAR(200)
    SET @NAME = ''

    DECLARE Col_Cursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT Name, Start, Length FROM ODS_SIEMENS_LAYOUT WHERE RecordType = '1'

    OPEN Col_Cursor
    FETCH NEXT FROM Col_Cursor INTO @NAME, @START, @LENGTH

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
    SET @SQL =  @NAME  + '=' + 'SUBSTRING(RAW_DATA,' + @START + ',' + @LENGTH + ')'
    FETCH NEXT FROM Col_Cursor INTO @NAME, @START, @LENGTH
    END


    CLOSE Col_Cursor
    DEALLOCATE Col_Cursor
```

I need to generate something like the below query:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_2
'AAA' = SUBSTRING(RAW_DATA,1,2)          
'BBB' = SUBSTRING(RAW_DATA,3,3)              
'CCC' = SUBSTRING(RAW_DATA,5,2)              
........
```

**Can I loop through each column to form the SQL Statement instead of manually coding 600 columns?**

Comment: Where does the need for looping come in?

Comment: A table with 600 columns??? Have you heard of normalization?

Comment: Well, it is absurd that you have 600 columns in a single table. That is bluntly outputting; "Terrible". But you could use sys.columns, then use the cursor over the temp table you can select those into.

Comment: Lets not jump to conclusions yet about the table design. There are valid use cases for wide tables like that. Not every database is a highly normalized database; some are optimized for fast access to a wide range of data (think something like how newegg screens and filters their data)

Comment: Yes there are valid uses for wide tables. 600 columns is not what I would call wide. That is beyond the limit of reasonable for anything I can think of. Even a staging table for a complicated ETL process would not come close to that many columns. Back to the topic at hand...why are we looping across columns?

Comment: My mistake. It has 6 columns with 600 rows.

Comment: Well that's certainly easier to stomach, but it's still not clear what you're trying to do here is. Can you flesh out your example a bit, or at least indicate what and why you're trying to loop over?

Comment: Well that is certainly a different animal. Why do you want a loop here and what are you really trying to do?

Comment: I add more detail about what I trying to do

Comment: Is raw_data a column you're trying to use the substring function on? Or are you just trying to construct a string literal that says 'AAA = substring(raw_data, 1, 2)'?

Comment: The raw_data is a column I am trying to use the substring function on.

Comment: I don't understand at all what you are trying to do. There are so many things that seem left of center here it is hard to know where to start. dynamic sql, a cursor, no explanation about what you are really trying to do. Why can't you just execute the query that you state you want as the output from this cursor?

Comment: I think a small sample of input and desired output could help understanding what you're trying to achieve...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the risk of sounding like [Clippy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Clippy-letter.PNG)... it looks like you're trying to import a flat file.  Is your RAW_DATA coming from a flat file somewhere?  If so you might look into using bulk insert:

[Use a Format File to Bulk Import Data](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178129%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)

If you are just asking how can you build your sql statement using the data from your column definition table... then the code you have is very close.  You want something like this:

```
DECLARE @COLUMNS varchar(max)
DECLARE @SUBCOLUMNS varchar(max)
DECLARE @NAME VARCHAR(200) 
DECLARE @START VARCHAR(200)  
DECLARE @LENGTH VARCHAR(200)
SET @NAME = ''

DECLARE Col_Cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT Name, Start, Length FROM ODS_SIEMENS_LAYOUT WHERE RecordType = '1'

OPEN Col_Cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM Col_Cursor INTO @NAME, @START, @LENGTH

set @SUBCOLUMNS = ''
set @COLUMNS = ''
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
SET @COLUMNS = @COLUMNS + @NAME  + ','
SET @SUBCOLUMNS = @SUBCOLUMNS + 'SUBSTRING(RAW_DATA,' + @START + ',' + @LENGTH + '),'
FETCH NEXT FROM Col_Cursor INTO @NAME, @START, @LENGTH
END


CLOSE Col_Cursor
DEALLOCATE Col_Cursor

set @COLUMNS = LEFT(@COLUMNS, len(@COLUMNS)-1) --get rid of last comma
set @SUBCOLUMNS = LEFT(@SUBCOLUMNS, len(@SUBCOLUMNS)-1) --get rid of last comma
print 'INSERT INTO TABLE_2 ' + '(' + @COLUMNS + ') SELECT ' + @SUBCOLUMNS + ' FROM RawDataTable'
```

You can take the text that prints and insert that SQL statement into your procedure that does the actual inserts.

Comment: The raw_data is coming from a flat file, but already stored as a maximum of 1500 characters string in a table. The idea for cursor part is I don't have to manually typing out all the codes. There will be 11 different RecordType with about 1300 rows, which mean  I have to manually typing out 1300 rows. I am hoping the cursor will automatically look through all the columns and gerenate the query. There are 3 tables, one for lookup (has name, start, length), one to select from (the lookup table tell the range of values to substring from this raw_data table), last one is the insert into table.

Comment: Ah, so you're just looking to generate the SQL Syntax for the insert statement by using your column definition table?  I updated my answer to show you how to do this.

Comment: There was a maximum text limitation for MS, so the text was cut-offs. If I want to insert one statment each time how can I do that? EX: INSERT INTO TABLE (Name1) SELECT SUBSTRING(#,#) FROM RawDataTable, and keep repeating the step until it reach last column name.

Comment: Instead of the final print statement, try select.  You can then copy the text from the grid and it should allow up to 65,535 characters.

Comment: Thanks. It work perfectly, but instead of copy and paste, how can I execute the statement like exec(@parameter) without any texts been cutting off. My manager suggested me to use the method I mentioned previously.

Comment: You shouldn't have any problem using an @parameter getting truncated if you define it as a VARCHAR(MAX).  Keep in mind though that if you paste the code into a stored procedure, SQL Server can cache a plan for it as opposed to using Dynamic SQL.  If the code's not going to change, a stored procedure would be more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Ahh I think I am beginning to unravel what you are trying to do. There is no need for a cursor or dynamic sql here at all. You just need to use a select statement as the values for your insert. Something like this maybe??

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_2(AAA, BBB, CCC)
SELECT SUBSTRING(RAW_DATA,1,2)          
, SUBSTRING(RAW_DATA,3,3)              
, SUBSTRING(RAW_DATA,5,2)      
FROM ODS_SIEMENS_LAYOUT 
WHERE RecordType = '1'
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, the idea for cursor part is I don't have to manually typing out all the codes. There will be 11 different RecordType with about 1300 rows, which mean  I have to manually typing out 1300 rows. I am hoping the cursor will automatically look through all the columns and gerenate the query.

Comment: Why would you have to type 1300 rows of anything? A slight modification to the above for each different record type should do it.